# Android GridView ItemClikListneter issue

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I created a `GridView` with item.xml that include image inside the `LinearLayout`.

Gridview code:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:columnWidth="150dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="15dip" >
        </GridView>
```

item.xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    >
</ImageView>
```

Then I added selector.xml for `LinearLayout` background to avoid showing selected area when click on item.

selector.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

After adding `android:clickable="true"` to the item.xml `LinearLayout`, `GridView` `ItemClickListner` does not work.Otherwise it works but does not apply selector.xml effect to the `LinearLayout`.I want to apply selector.xml effect for the `LinearLayout` and works `ItemClickListner` also.

Pls help me to fix this issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the attribute `android:focussable=false` to the ImageView in item.xml. this should do the trick.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focussable=false
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    >
</ImageView>
```

Since you are assigning clickable True to this ImageView, it gets the focus by default, thus not allowing your GridView item to be clicked. So setting it to non focussable state will help you achieve both the click events.

Answer (score 0):

remove android:clickable="true"  from linear layout and imageview of **item.xml** layout and add in imageview this three parameter

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

after that make an xml  in drawable **background.xml**  with something like this parameter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/focusedcolor"
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/selectedcolor" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/normalcolor" />
</selector>
```

after that add in your **item.xml** in linear layout

```
  android:background="@drawable/background"
```

here in my code i have **colors.xml** in **values**  folder something like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <color name="focusedcolor">#b6c4c5</color>
 <color name="selectedcolor">#ff33ffff</color>
 <color name="normalcolor">#f7ff1f</color>
 </resources>
```

instead of color u can also use image from drawable folder if u want to image than in **background.xml** you have to change

```
 android:drawable="@color/focusedcolor" line by 

 android:drawable="@drawable/imagename"
```

Comment: what is the issue with android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" background.xml (as my code selector.xml)??

Comment: selector.xml effect does not apply because of android:focusable="false"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false" . And I don't want to apply colors for the Layout background.

Comment: @it works for me as  i have used for listview's row xml u have to set background to the LinearLyaout of item.xml as i have written u can change a color if u want transparent color as u have used in ur selector.xml check it